# How to get topic associated with each document using pyspark(2.1.0) LdA?

Tags: pyspark, data-mining, lda, topic-modeling, data-processing

I am using LDAModel of pyspark to get topics from corpus. My goal is to find **topics associated with each document**. For that purpose I tried to set **topicDistributionCol** as per Docs. Since I am new to this, I am not sure what is the purpose of this column.

```
from pyspark.ml.clustering import LDA
lda_model = LDA(k=10, optimizer="em").setTopicDistributionCol("topicDistributionCol")
// documents is valid dataset for this lda model
lda_model = lda_model.fit(documents)
transformed = lda_model.transform(documents)

topics = lda_model.describeTopics(maxTermsPerTopic=num_words_per_topic)
print("The topics described by their top-weighted terms:")
print topics.show(truncate=False)
```

It lists all topics with termIndices and termWeights.

[image]

below code will give me topicDistributionCol. Here each row is for each document.

```
print transformed.select("topicDistributionCol").show(truncate=False)
```

[image]

I want to get document topic matrix like this. Is it possible with pysparks LDA model ?

```
doc | topic 
1   |  [2,4]
2   |  [3,4,6]
```

Note : I have done this using gensims LDA model earlier with following code. But I need to use pysparks LDA model.

```
texts = [[word for word in document.lower().split() if word not in stoplist] for document in documents]
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(texts)

corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in texts]
doc_topics = LdaModel(corpus=corpus, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=10, passes=10)
## to fetch topics for one document
vec_bow = dictionary.doc2bow(text[0])
Topics = doc_topics[vec_bow]
Topic_list = [x[0] for x in Topics]
## topic list is [1,5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using toPandas can help:

```
df_p = transformed.select('topicDistributionCol').toPandas()
df_p1 = df_p.topicDistribution.apply(lambda x:np.array(x))
df_p2 = pd.DataFrame(df_p1.tolist()).apply(lambda x:x.argmax(),axis=1)
df_p3 = df_p2.reset_index()
df_p3.columns = ['doc','topic']
df_p3
```

Comment: How do you go about this if you used a pipeline? I have a pipeline which I can access the LDA stage, but from there, topicDistributionCol is a Param object, and doesn't have toPandas ...

Answer (score 1):

**Don't take your data out of spark!** That defeats the purpose of using spark. If you don't actually need it, use scikit.

Adding onto the answer provided by @kevin, once you have ran the transform method on the LDA model `transformed = model.transform(input_data)` to get your topic distribution you should see a dataframe with this column:

```
+--------------------+
|  topicDistribution |
+--------------------+
|[8.11971897779803...|
|[0.00341037397939...|
|[0.00141274604502...|
```

This is a list of measurements for each row (prediction) to all the vertices in the n-dimensional triangular simplex shape that **is** the LDA model.

You can employ this handy little udf below to automatically map the **ONE** top topic **for each row** by running it over the probability distribution in the col above.

In a nutshell, we are finding the maximum probability in the list which is your top topic. The probability measurements are in the **same order as your topics**.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

@f.udf(returnType=IntegerType())
def top_topic(topic_dist):
    dict = {prob: i for i, prob in enumerate(topic_dist)}
    return dict.get(max(topic_dist))
```

If you just want to map the **ONE** top topic **for each row** in the distribution your time complexity will be O(n).

However if you seek to model multiple relationships for each document you can modify the method as follows to support up to **k** topics which will give you a complexity of O(n ^ k) where k is the number of topics you want to return. So keep k reasonable ;)

```
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, IntegerType
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

@f.udf(returnType=ArrayType(IntegerType()))
def top_3_topics(topic_dist):
    k = 3
    res = []
    mutable = list(topic_dist)
    dict = {prob: i for i, prob in enumerate(topic_dist)}
    for i in range(k):
        current = dict.get(max(mutable))
        res.append(current)
        mutable[current] = 0.0

    del mutable
    return res
```

When finished you will get this:

```
+--------------------+-----+
|  topicDistribution |topic|
+--------------------+-----+
|[8.11971897779803...|   19|
|[0.00341037397939...|   12|
|[0.00141274604502...|   19|
```

Or this (with an ArrayType column if you want more than one topic):

```
+--------------------+------------+
|  topicDistribution |       topic|
+--------------------+------------+
|[8.11971897779803...|  [19, 1, 7]|
|[0.00341037397939...| [12, 16, 4]|
|[0.00141274604502...|[19, 16, 11]|
```

This is designed so that the topic column is appended to your existing results.

Name your topics and join your topic labels to your results automatically:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, StructType, StructField

schema = StructType([
            StructField("topic", StringType(), True),
            StructField("topic_name", StringType(), True)])

data = [('0', 'politics'),
        ('1', 'global'),
        ('2', 'crime')]

        topics_data = self.spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
        results = results.join(topics_data, 'topic', 'left')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an easy answer for this question. Do the following:

```
transformed.take(10)
```

The last column of the output will be "topicDistribution", which is document-topic distribution.